# Setting attribute values in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I have a template that contains the following fragment:

```
<spark class="col-12" value="80"></spark>
```

I also have a variable accessible to this template as {{ratio}} such that if I change my fragment to:

```
<spark class="col-12" value="80"></spark>
Ratio: {{ratio}}
```

the correct ratio will be displayed on a page.

This is what does not work:

```
<spark class="col-12" value="{{ratio}}"></spark>
```

which results in "{{ratio}}" string being displayed.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Is `spark` a directive you made, or third-party? If it's the former, please show us the source.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the built-in directives for adding attribute values from the scope, for example ng-src, ng-style, ng-href, so on.

[Documentation for the built-in directives](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/docs/api/ng/directive)

Comment: <input type="text" value="{{ratio}}"></input> works just fine, but 
<spark class="col-12" ng-value="{{ratio}}"></spark> although no longer produces "{{ratio}}" string still does not result in the correct <spark> behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Will ng-attr work for you? ng-attr-value="{{ratio}}"

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#-ngattr-attribute-bindings

Comment: thanks, but both <spark value="{{ratio}}" /> and <spark ng-attr-value="{{ratio}}" /> result in the same behavior: "{{ratio}}" string displayed...